# Struggling with Windows installer in a Sedatech PC

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, wubi

I just bought this PC:
[Sedatech PC Office](http://www.pixmania.ie/desktop-computer/sedatech-pc-office-intel-i5-3570-4x3-4ghz-8gb-ram-1000gb-240gb-ssd-usb-3-0-full-hd-1080p-wifi-80-psu-win-7/12100875-a.html)
and right away I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 with the Windows Installer.

Everything goes fine until the end of [installation step 5](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows). At that point the progress window disappears and nothing happens, nothing has been installed and all is almost exactly as it was just before double clicking on wubi.exe.

I say "almost exactly" because in the partition where I ask Ubuntu to be installed (different than the Windows 7 partition) there is an ubuntu folder with a couple of files and folders, but nothing usable. Needless to say, there is no dual boot when I reboot.

I have repeated this again and again. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at (or pastebin and post the link of) the log file from the `%TEMP%` directory. It will show more info about what went wrong. It's called `wubi-12.10-revxxx.log`. Note if Windows is installed in `UEFI` mode then Wubi won't work anyway, so you should do a normal dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all new computers ship configured to boot in EFI (aka UEFI) mode, and the WUBI tool you're trying to use is incompatible with an EFI-mode boot. Thus, my suspicion is that your attempt was doomed to fail, and you should instead try a more traditional dual-boot configuration.